# Universal keyboard remapper

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I've just bought new a keyboard and there are no drivers, there are some special keys mapped to some actions like switch to desktop or play/pause media player. I need a software that intercepts these actions and assigns them a different action. Does anyone know a solution?

Thank you for help.

Comment: Operating System?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a tutorial on how to remap keys in Windows 7 using **SharpKeys**:

- [Map Any Key to Any Key on Windows 7 / XP / Vista](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/map-any-key-to-any-key-on-windows-xp-vista/)

Answer (score 1):

I prefer [KeyTweak](http://webpages.charter.net/krumsick/) (for Windows systems only) because:

- It's easier to use
- Shows you what's being generated

I've tried both on my Samsung laptop because it seems to be generating the same scan codes for both Enter and NumEnter and I have software that uses them differently.

Answer (score 1):

Also consider AutoHotkey -- free and incredibly versatile, although its scripting-only interface can make it a bear to use.